500 error while integrating EBS with Ping
I'm trying to integrate EBS with Ping SSO, I have configured Ping suite to send the headers to EBS accessgate and pointed the EBS to use Ping URL. When I try to test the SSO, EBS AccessGate show error as "Internal server error. The server encountered an unknow error, possibly due to misconfiguration. Contact the server administrater: [no address given]". Any idea what it says for "no address given"? Have any one faced this and fixed?
The flow is, User enters EBS URL, then EBS redirects to Ebs AccessGate and then AccessGate redirect the Authn request to Ping, Ping authenticates the user and send the information back to EBS AccessGate as http header. Then EBS AccessGate use that header to validate the user information in the EBS FND table and create session for User and allow the user to login.

"no address given" probably just means no contact email address has been included in the config. It's not really relevant, particularly if you are the one configuring it anyway. You will need to look at the server logs to find the actual error.
